# How to retrieve Blaze template name from inside?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to use the name of a meteor template from inside:

```
<template name="blaModal">
    <div class="modal fade" id="{{templateName}}"> 
    </div>
</template>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global helper, that resolves the current Template's instance and returns it's view-name (with `Template.` prefix removed):

*/imports/startup/client/helpers.js*

```js
Template.registerHelper('templateName', function () {
  const instance = Template.instance()
  const { view } = instance
  const { name } = view
  return name.replace('Template.', '')
})
```

Comment: The real question is why do you need to do this? I feel as though you are going in a round about way to accomplish something that is very simple.

Comment: With this you can easily generate an i18n pattern for each template for example to display a title for each current route.